# For Loops for Items not in the list Python

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, nested-lists

I am trying to bypass exceptions for items excluded from a list. I have two functions; I call the first function indside the second one. When I add an else/elif clause to the conditional statement below, an error occurs: `" 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"` (points to line 16 in the first function). I presume I am passing a string to a function wich only take integers but unsure how to avoid it.
What is the best way of eliminating items excluded from a given list inside a for loop? Thanks!

```
def similarity(country1, country2):
   return abs(country1[1]-country2[1]) + abs(country1[2]-country2[2]) + 
         abs(country1[3]-country2[3]) # << Line 16



def top_similar_countries(medal_list, number):

   z = 0
   for medal in medal_list:
      if prompted_country == medal[0]:
         z = medal

   score_list = []

   for medal in medal_list:
      score = similarity(z, medal)
      country_score = [score, medal[0]]       
      score_list.append(country_score)

   score_list.sort()
   requested_count  =  score_list[1:(num_count+1)]

   for i in range (len(requested_count)):
      print "%s: \t (%d)"%(requested_count[i][1], requested_count[i][0])
```

Comment: You are passing `z` (an `int`) to `similarty()` as `country1`, but `country1` is being used as a `list` in that function. So the error is obvious.

Comment: Please mark the line in question in your code. Usually this is done via comment #.

Comment: Such tiny errors can be caught easily by placing `print` statements here and there to find out what kind of values do you have in your variables before you run into the error. For example by placing `print '%s %s' % (country1, country2)` as the first statement of the `similarity()` function you can print the incoming parameters. Note that the `%s` format specifier works with everything in python.

Comment: This might be unrelated to the answer, but where do you get the value for prompted_country in the line `code if prompted_country == medal[0]:`

Comment: unrelated: you could use a `Counts = namedtuple('Counts', 'country bronze silver gold')` for readability instead of indexes e.g., `country1[1]` would be `country1.bronze`.

Comment: The value for prompted_country comes from raw_input() in the test code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the replies. All I wanted to do is to avoid an error message printed when a country is not on the list.Icould not avoid it by setting z to 'None', and printing 'No matches were found' in an else clause, or setting z to != 'None' in elif of the if statement. I have to search the prompted_country (from raw_input) in a list of lists to calculate scores for this country and all others via function similarity and print the closest n countries (the n is also obtained from raw_input). That said I need to print 0 or 'No matches found' without raising an exception . Thanks again!

Comment: I added a print statement to verify the value of z, it printed a list: Please input a country ==> Poland
Poland
Enter a number of top matches to display ==> 5
5
Top 5 countries in 2012 Olympics
['Poland', 24, 26, 32, 82]
China:   (24)
Great Britain:   (27)
United States:   (28)
Germany:   (38)
Japan:   (44)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass index to an integer:

```
>>> 1[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Don't pass `z` (an `int`) to the `similarity()` function that expects two sequences. It happens if none of the countries in the `medal_list` is `prompted_country`. You could raise an exception in this case:

```
z = None
for country, *medals in medal_list:
    if prompted_country == country:
        z = [country] + medals
        break
else: # no break
    raise ValueError("%r not found in %r" % (prompted_country, medal_list))
```